# What DML commands can be allowed / limited on a reporting server?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a largish database (PostgreSQL 9.1) which I'm preparing to replicate using streaming replication. The 2nd server will be used for reporting and backup purposes. When building reports, it's often useful to build "temporary" tables. By using "temporary" I mean tables which are considered scratch, but which are not using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Can I force a user to create new tables only their separate schema? Will these schema changes have any impact on streaming replication? The master server only ever has changes in the public schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, replicated database clusters are complete replicants of the original cluster (e.g. does not support replicating only a certain subset of databases/schemas etc ) and may only host read only transactions.